# Select by Attribute on Date field using wildcards?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

I have a date field within a file geodatabase (10.1).

An example of a value in this field: **19/11/2012 08:49:56**

I want to select all rows where the time is between 9pm to 11pm AND 6am to 9am.

I don't care what day, month, year it is.  So I want to make use of wildcards to ignore these values.

What would be the correct statement to put in the Select By Attributes to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to split the field in two with space as separator? Then you can get a field with time only, which probably is more convenient to filter from.

Comment: Shouldn't this be more generally stated as "how do I select by time of day on a date field?"  ?

Comment: I guess you have referred to the esri help. But here is the link   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000

Answer (score 1):

If you date is stored as a date you can use this:

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "Date_filed" ) = 6 
or
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "Date_filed" ) = 7 
or
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "Date_filed" ) = 8
```

IF your date is stored as a text field you could use this:

It's a little ugly, but you could use this

```
"Date_filed" LIKE '___________06:_____'
or
"Date_filed" LIKE '___________07:_____'
or
"Date_filed" LIKE '___________08:_____'
```

and just change the numbers to indicate the hours you are interested in.

or this should work:

```
"Date_filed" LIKE '% 06:%'
or
"Date_filed" LIKE '% 07:%'
or
"Date_filed" LIKE '% 08:%'
```

but as Martin suggested splitting the datetime up and adding a time field might be the best way to go.

Comment: Dont you need to put date after the LIKE statement?  Ill do some testing now...

Comment: In the first query the underscores represent the characters of the dates. In the second the using the wildcard then space then your hour marker followed by : should allow for selecting only the hours, since there is no other position in your datetime that will meet that criteria.

Comment: This (and variations) is not working for me,  Keep getting 'an invalid SQL statement was used'

Comment: You are changing "date_field" to the name of your datetime field right? Also you may need to change "date_field" to [date_field].

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer, to deal with date format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the subs in the date field without creating a new field for hour.
  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079671/find-records-with-a-date-field-in-the-last-24-hours) using the day sub.
Just switch to the hour sub and use the between.